# Load a Python module and call its functions within Delphi code without ExecString

Tags: delphi, lazarus, python4delphi

I've been looking around for some way to call python functions (using Python4Delphi) within my delphi code without direct need for TPythonEngine.ExecStrings execution.

My base idea is to load a module, for instance, `example.py` looking like:

```py
def DoExample(pStr: str) -> str:
    pStr = "Example: " + pStr
    return pStr
```

And call it like (disclaimer: example of behavior I'd like to have, not actual P4D behavior):

```pascal
MyPythonEngine := TPythonEngine.Create(nil);
{necessary version, flags and LoadDll}
MyPythonModule := TPythonModule.Create(nil);
{necessary configs again}
MyImportedFunction := {Load the DoExample somehow and store it in this variable}
ResultOfMyImportedFunction := MyImportedFunction("This is an example"); {This should be Example: This is an example}
```

I could also achieve my goal by adapting the `example.py`:

```py
import sys

def DoExample(pStr: str) -> str:
    pStr = "Example: " + pStr
    return pStr

DoExample(sys.argv[1])
```

And call it like I would in cli, still need to get its result.

I've intensively read the Demos and didn't find a reasonable answer to my problem. Also no documentation for further reading (or atleast I couldn't find it).

Also I don't know if this approach is even possible due to lack of documentation.

tl;dr
I'd like load a python script, take one of its defined functions, call it within delphi and retrieve its result into a varaible.

Thanks in Advance! Happy New Year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from pyscripter on [Delphi-Praxis](https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/10753-load-a-python-module-and-call-its-functions-within-delphi-code-without-execstring/?tab=comments#comment-85628) forum:

```pascal
var SL := TStringList.Crete;
try
  SL.LoadFromFile('example.py');
  PyEngine.ExecStrings(SL);
  var Res := MainModule.DoExample('input');
finally
  SL.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).